# 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine error

Tags: sql-server

I am facing this issue and i tried every method changing cpu from 32 bit to 64 bit but could not find solution.Help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got rid of this issue.Download  Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable.That's all. Problem solved.

Link to download: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255